# Flag for cross-compiling for ARMv6l with arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc

Tags: c, linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I have some difficulty to cross-compile a simple HelloWorld in C. The host is Ubuntu X86_64 and the target is ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l) running Linux kernel 2.6.21.7

If i try:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static -march=armv6 hello.c -o hello
```

I get a segmentation fault on the target. File command output is:

```
hello: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/Linux 2.6.31, BuildID[sha1]=0x0c77ad13c58160eab9dcbf2feeeaf4d27a4319cb, not stripped
```

I don't see any "armv6l" flag in the GCC documentation. Is it possible to cross-compile for this architecture with GCC?

Comment: what about `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -o hello` ?? If this is not working, then problem may be in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I did try your solution before posting. I posted below the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked with sourcery: https://sourcery.mentor.com/sgpp/lite/arm/portal/release2029

After the installation, I had to reboot my computer then it compiled fine with this command:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc -o hello -static hello.c
```